# Jquery UI progressbar is not getting initialized?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, jquery-ui-progressbar

I am trying to use jQuery UI progress bar in my web app.
But that is not getting displayed. I am using a DWR call to get the upload status. Before using Jquery UI progressbar, i just displayed the status returned from server as just as it is, to make sure the data coming from server. It was working fine.

**The Code**

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var progressbar = $("#jqProgressBar");
progressbar.css({
    "width"  : "200px",
    "height" : "10px"
});
$("#jqProgressBar").progressbar({'value':0});
});
function statusUpdate() {
FileUploadProgressListener.getFileUploadStatus(function(status){
    if(status >= 95)
    {
        status = 100;
        $("#jqProgressBar").progressbar({'value':status});
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#jqProgressBar").progressbar({'value':status});
        window.setTimeout(statusUpdate, 200);
    }
});
return true;
  }
</script>
<h4>File Upload</h4>
    <iframe id="uploadFrameID"
       name="uploadFrame"
       height="0" width="0"
       frameborder="0"
       scrolling="yes"></iframe>
<form action="ProfileImageUpload"
     enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
 onsubmit="setTimeout('statusUpdate()', 1000)" target="uploadFrame">

  <input type="file" name="fileupload_upload" value="Upload File">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
 <div id="jqProgressBar"></div>
</body>
```

Any suggestions!!!

Comment: Do you have jQuery-ui js and css included in the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this line in the code that changes the value:

```
    $("#jqProgressBar").progressbar(status);
```